# Bulk change of shortcuts destination

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, alias

I have a folder (in Windows) containing a lot of shortcuts different files in different subdirectories of the folder "Important" on the disk C:.

Now I need to transfer the whole folder "Important" to the disk D:.

How to change all aliases so that they will point to the new destinations?

(Nothing but the drive letter will be changed in the destination paths.)

Comment: What do you mean aliases? Doskey macros? Symbolic links? Shortcuts? Something else?

Comment: Shortcuts - I apologize for the bad term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on an NTFS system, there is a Windows service called [Distributed Link Tracking Client](https://www.windows-security.org/windows-service/distributed-link-tracking-client). In short, it tracks where you move files to, so that if you have shortcuts that point to a file that was moved, the shortcut gets updated automatically.

In other words, you could just move your Important folder, and the shortcuts should continue to work.

Comment: You answer was so promising, both disk (source C: and destination D:) are NTFS, Distributed Link Tracking Client (TrkWks) is continuously running (automatic startup type), but no one link was updated in practice.

Comment: Did you try running one? It's not actually updated until accessed.

Comment: Yes, I do, I moved the full directory to D: and tried double click to original shortcuts, all of them (I tried about 10) gave me message box that target item was been changed or removed and asked me if I want to remove this shortcut. After about 15 minutes I tried double click again with the same result, so I moved that full directory back to C: and all shortcuts were functional again.

Comment: Hmm. It worked for me. Perhaps it's an OS difference. I'm on Windows 10. You?

Comment: Windows 7. I even tried moving one target of shortcut to the same disk (C: to C:) to other directory with the same result (not success). I double checked that Distributed Link Tracking Client is running and all 3 services on which it is dependent, too. Something is bad on my side. Nevertheless I thank you, your answer is very good and I vote it up (in spite i have not enough reputation to see it).

Comment: along with the Distributed Link Tracking, is the Indexing Service also acting on both disks?

Answer (score 0):

The Shortcut command was removed in Windows 98. There is no command line interface to shortcuts. You can write your own command. This prints stuff about a shortcut.

```
'on error resume next 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments 
set lnk = WshShell.CreateShortcut(Ag(0)) 
wscript.echo Ag(0) & vbcrlf & lnk.hotkey & vbcrlf & lnk.TargetPath
```

To use

```
cscript //nologo c:\folder\sc.vbs c:\folder\shortcut.lnk
```

Comment: I am sorry but your answer does not solve my problem - it only print the target path of a given link.